# Error when creating bean with type java.io.File [Ambiguous constructor argument types]

Tags: java, spring, file, ambiguous

I have the following spring bean configuration

```
  <bean id="fileBean" class="java.io.File">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="$prop{file.path.property}" />    
  </bean>
```

I'm getting the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'fileBean' defined in class path resource [context.xml]:  
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
[java.net.URI]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct 
bean references as constructor arguments?
```

There is only one constructor for java.io.File with a single String parameter so I'm not sure why this is ambiguous.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found [this link](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-263) that explains what is happening.  It turns out that **spring will match arguments by type if there is no argument index specified**.  In this case spring takes my single String argument and passes it to java.io.File constructor that takes **TWO** strings.  This can be fixed by specifying the constructor-arg index.

```
<bean id="fileBean" class="java.io.File">
  <constructor-arg index="0"
                   type="java.lang.String" 
                   value="$prop{file.path.property}" />    
</bean>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just my two cents here: I had the exact same problem today.  I have a unit test to check if Spring can read my XML config and generate all necessary beans.  It was failing because I was editing the wrong XML file.  I was editing a "dist" version from an Ant build, instead of the correct version from source control.

Lesson learned: Read those Spring exception messages (with XML file paths) *very closely*!

Comment: Same happened to me, the exception turned out to be in another xml file that I have been editing