# How is constructor chosen in spring for beans defined in xml with parent?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-3

I am working with Spring 3.1.0. I am trying to understand the way spring is reading its xml files. I am trying to understand how spring deals with ambiguous conditions in the bean definitions.

For example

I have `Alarm.java`

```
package com.anshbansal.alarm2;

public class Alarm {

    private String type;
    private int volume;
    private int hour;

    public Alarm() {
    }

    public Alarm(String type, int volume, int hour) {
        this.type = type;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public Alarm(String type, int volume) {
        this.type = type;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public Alarm(int volume, String type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setVolume(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alarm{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", volume=" + volume +
                ", hour=" + hour +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My spring xml file `alarm2.xml` is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <bean id="propertyRandom" abstract="true">
              <constructor-arg value="23" type="int"/>
       </bean>


       <bean id="alarm1" class="com.anshbansal.alarm2.Alarm" parent="propertyRandom">
              <constructor-arg value="10" type="int"/>
              <constructor-arg value="Ringing" />
       </bean>


</beans>
```

There is ambiguity as it is not instantly clear which `int` will go into volume and which will go into hour. If I print I get the following

```
Alarm{type='Ringing', volume=23, hour=10}
```

So how does spring read the xml file to resolve which constructor to call? Parent first, then bean? Is it documented somewhere?

I know that there are ways like specifying `index` and `name` as attributes but I should also be aware about how to deal with such ambiguous conditions. That's why I am asking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection),

> Constructor argument resolution matching occurs using the argument’s
>   type. If no potential ambiguity exists in the constructor arguments of
>   a bean definition, then the order in which the constructor arguments
>   are defined in a bean definition is the order in which those arguments
>   are supplied to the appropriate constructor when the bean is being
>   instantiated.

I found the following answer which explains the spring behavior in selecting a constructor.

> If you specify a constructor-arg without index, the greediest
>   constructor that can be satisfied with the given arguments will be
>   invoked (matching the arguments by type). In the case of java.io.File,
>   this is the File(String parent, String child) constructor: Your String
>   argument matches both by type, so the algorithm uses that constructor.

[reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327255/error-when-creating-bean-with-type-java-io-file-ambiguous-constructor-argument)
[reference 2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-263)

When inheriting from a parent, the constructor arguments get merged (same as merging property collections). In your case, after the merging the child bean constructor arguments will be

```
<constructor-arg value="23" type="int"/>
<constructor-arg value="10" type="int"/>
<constructor-arg value="Ringing" />
```

For ambiguous scenarios, use either the index or the constructor argument name.

Comment: That doesn't explain how the particular `int` of parent was assigned to volume and not hour. Can you please explain?

Comment: Revised the answer to mention merging

Comment: Thanks for the info. How are you finding this info?

Comment: Looking at the code. The spring source code is on github.